# How to handle authentication when user is offline using Angular PWA?

Tags: angular, authentication, identityserver4, progressive-web-apps

I have an [angular](https://angular.io/) application with [PWA](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started). My main concern is to allow the user to use the app while offline without internet connection.
The question is: how can I accomplish that with [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.io/) and 
[OIDC](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) ?
I'm considering the following solution: Assuming I have a valid "Refresh Token", then as long as the internet connection is offline, I would consider the user as still authenticated. Of course, this means the user has already logged in while "online".

Any suggestions for handling "login" while still "offline". For example, Windows OS uses some kind of "local storage" to authentication users, even while they have no internet connection.
Any suggestions, appreciated

Comment: Good question, and something that's really needed.  From what I know, there's really no way to do this in a secure manner.  Native iOS APPs and Windows have a way to securely access local password storage, but I've yet to see anything from PWA.  Local Storage can be easily spoofed, and any attempt to store encrypt a password would also required the encryption code (and key) be included in the script.  Alternatively, perhaps you allow the user to log transactions locally, but only commit them when they perform a server authentication?

Comment: I'm already logging transactions locally and committing them when back online. My concern is with "expired tokens" and allowing the user to "use" the application even when they are "offline".

Comment: Some related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48130973, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58994880, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60704511

Answer (score 5):

Assume that the user has an internet connection and login to the app:

- Save the Refresh Token `localstorage.setItem('resfreshToken', yourToken)`
- When the user opens the app check the `localstorage.getItem('refereshToken')`
- If it's not null or empty then the user is authenticated.

As per my knowledge `refresh tokens` do not expire so that you can always use the refresh token to get a new token. So when the internet connection is back you can use the `refresh token` to request a new `access token` and submit the data changes.

Comment: If I have a Refresh Token, then I can assume I have "valid" credentials. As long as I'm still "disconnected" from the internet (which could be for hours) , and there is no way to "reevaluate" the validity, I can assume I'm "OKAY".
When connection is back, and before submitting all data changes, I'll use the refresh token to request a new "access token" and resume work normally.
The question is, does oidc.js library has any built in support for such functionality, or it just works on "expiry dates" and timers ?

Comment: Fyi refresh tokens can expire, but the expiration time is not

Comment: Expiration time of refresh tokens is normally a lot longer than regular access tokens

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment:

> My concern is with "expired tokens" and allowing the user to "use" the application even when they are "offline"

I'd create some kind of validation inside the app that limits the amount of time that user can use the application being offline, like a timestamp. Once this time expires, you could remove the access/refresh token and force login (i.e. force the user to be online again and run a new authentication/authorization process).

Answer (score 1):

As I see the OIDC has no features like that.

You can check in an [interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) if the user is [online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine). If not you can  use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) to store the request.

There is an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine#Example) that you can subscribe to with [Renderer2 listen](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen). If event is happened notify the service to try to get the operations from IndexedDB and replay them after refreshing the token.

If you use redux you can also save the actions that was not able to finish.