# PWA offline login, it's possible?

Tags: authentication, local-storage, progressive-web-apps, offline

i am new in PWA and i was wondering if it´s possible to authenticate a user offline. I mean that if you can have a file in the local storage with the information of the users to perform the authentication. 
This file would be saved for the first time that any user authenticates with an internet connection, to then allow the authentication of any of the other users offline. Is it possible? Is it safe?
Any advice please? Thanks

Comment: What could the users actually do (while offline) if you authenticate then? Do you anticipate many of your users being offilne? Just wondering.

Comment: They would register a travel coupon (form with travel data) on a device thet will be fixed in the vehicle. User are drivers who can change assigned vehicles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not actually authenticate them because that would require hitting an identity service like Auth0, Cognito, etc.

Hoever....(modern tech is great)

If you leverage the Authn authentication you could hook into device authentication like Windows Hello. I will be honest this is way more difficult than it should be IMO. But the actual verification is done all on the client (way too deep to cover here).

But....

You wont be able to get an authentication token from your identity service since you are offline, just verify the identity.

Now to deal with the coupon that would not require actual authentication that you could do. As far as applying it to an online purchase you would of course need to be online to complete that process. But you can cache the transaction and sync it up later.

I hope this helps. It is not a short answer sort of question :)