# How to secure a PWA with password for offline use?

Tags: authentication, progressive-web-apps

I want to be able to download info from a server in a PWA using server-held credentials. However I also want to be able to use this downloaded data offline in the PWA. This should be protected by a password on the device.

I can't see a secure way to do this as being JS, even the hash function to read the password would be available to a malicious person.

Is there any proper pattern for doing this? If not, this would seem to be a massive oversight in the whole PWA pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been searching for an answer to this question. [This page](https://dbushell.com/2020/06/08/pwa-web-crypto-encryption-auto-sign-in-redux-persist/) describes encryption of the app's local storage using the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto). The author also describes several approaches to 'auto sign in' which appear to depend on the browser.
I've yet to try it myself, a few other things to do first, but it is a clear and convincing article.